# http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" becomes default on other page on IE 11 with StrokeReader serial port ActiveX

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, serial-port, activex

I have a header that I include on different pages.
Inside header I have

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

It works on one page, but when I click a link to another page with same header it becomes default internet explorer 11. something is overriding my meta tag.
I'll include an image with dev tool explanation. Can anyone point to right article or if you had incounter this problem can you tell me where is the problem?

BTW I am using Serial Port reader program that supports only IE-10
but PC is windows 10 and I can't have IE-10 there.

First Page where meta tag works,

[image: First Page]

Then I click Detail link it brings me to the page within same header, but there I loose meta tag.

[image]

and error in console if it is somehow related to this issue

[image]

Comment: I started <cfabort> on every line of code and when reach Coldfusiion's <CFORM>, <CFINPUT> and <CFSELECT>  tags, I lost meta tag ie=10. here it was becoming IE defalut 11.  I put regular HTML Tags and it worked. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Good detective work. If you look at the generated html, apparently the CF UI tags mess with the order of the `<meta>` tag within `<head>`, causing the page to revert to the default in IE. Guess that is another reason to switch to plain html tags :-) You should write that up as an answer so it is more visible (and folks can vote on it too).

Comment: I validated generated html in html5 validator and it was telling me that I have extra body tag and not matching div and td elements. I then indented, properly nested all the code in the page. but didn't help but after removing cftags in the form errors disappeared.

Comment: Interesting. Probably depends on the exact code.  My test was with an empty `<cfform>`: http://trycf.com/gist/23d0295a9c2285170e78e1d5c0ac8379/acf2016?theme=monokai .  I copied the generated code to an .html page and viewed it in IE. As is, it registers as IE11, but after moving the `<meta>` tag it displays as IE10.

Answer (score 1):

I started debugging with `<cfabort>` on every line of code and when I reach Coldfusion's `<CFORM>`, `<CFINPUT>` and `<CFSELECT>` tags, I lost meta tag ie=10 . Here it was becoming IE defalut 11. I put regular HTML Tags and it worked. Thanks for your time guys.